# How do browsers know what range to request when making a partial http range request?

Tags: http, range, http-get

Let us say the server does serve partial get requests (returns 'Accept-Ranges: bytes').

A user opens a 100 second video that is 100 000 bytes long ('Content-Length: 100 000'). The user then decides to skip to second 30 of the video. I assume the browser would send a request along the lines of:

```
GET /video.mp4
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US,en
Host: website.com
Range: bytes=30 000-99 999
```

But how does the browser guess what should be the start of the byte range (in this example, 30 000)?